# How can I solve append issue for an image using ajax

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

My first script provides to random image as you can see below

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- include Cycle plugin -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cloud.github.com/downloads/malsup/cycle/jquery.cycle.all.latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var $t = jQuery.noConflict();
    $t(function () {
        $t('.slideshow').cycle({
            fx: 'fade' 
        });
    });
</script>
```

It works when I add some images like that

```
<div class="news_area_left">
     <div class="slideshow" style="position: relative; ">
        <img src="../../banner_image/nemo.jpg" width="154px" height="108px"/>
  <img src="../../banner_image/up.jpg" width="154px" height="108px" />

</div>
    </div>
```

But when I add my second script which get images as you can see

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {

        $.ajax({
            type: "get", url: "Home/Oku", data: {}, dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {

                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

                   var newFirmDiv= $(' <img src="../../banner_image/' + data[i] + '" width="154px" height="108px"/>');
                    $(".slideshow").append(newFirmDiv);

                }
            }
        });
    });

</script>
```

Finally I try to use my dynamic images in my "slideshow div" but the effect does not work

```
<div class="news_area_left">
     <div class="slideshow" style="position: relative; ">
       </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run `$t('.slideshow').cycle` after you have dynamically inserted your images. Also you need to append to the "slideshow" class and not the "firmShowCase" class.

See this jsFiddle I've created http://jsfiddle.net/davew9999/sgUeq/

**HTML**

```
<div class="news_area_left">
     <div class="slideshow" style="position: relative; ">
         <img src="http://activephilosophy.files.wordpress.com/2009/09/number1.jpg" width="154px" height="108px"/>
         <img src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/h/Y/i/C/Y/W/red-rounded-square-with-number-2-md.png" width="154px" height="108px"/>
     </div>
</div>​
```

**JavaScript**

```
var $t = jQuery.noConflict();

var newFirmDiv = $t('<img src="http://www.mosamuse.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/number3.png" width="154px" height="108px"/>');
$t(".slideshow").append(newFirmDiv);

var anotherDiv = $t('<img src="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-_A_8UYb0zIQ/Te5lpI9iZ3I/AAAAAAABgWk/sErDyHjEhPw/s1600/number-4.jpg" width="154px" height="108px"/>');
$t(".slideshow").append(anotherDiv);

$t(function() {
    $t('.slideshow').cycle({
        fx: 'fade'
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you update your answer with your updated code. If you could post the HTML, JavaScript and any related CSS

Comment: I can't tell from your code exactly what scripts run in what order but it looks like you are inserting img tags into the slideshow **after** you have called `$t('.slideshow').cycle`. Check my jsFiddle again, I am calling `$t('.slideshow').cycle` **after** inserting the img tags